# Problem with xacro:if value="${model_type == A_model_type}"

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to set up a Xacro where one section is based on a Model type passed as an argument (the first line below would be an external argument).  No matter what model_type is set to, model A, B and C get included.  I can get this to work by having a separate variable set to true/false for each model, but it's ugly.  The following always loads all three models. I'm using Indigo.

```
<!-- The model we want loaded -->
<xacro:property name="model_type" value="3"/>

<!-- The different possibilities -->
<xacro:property name="A_model_type" value="2"/>
<xacro:property name="B_model_type" value="3"/>
<xacro:property name="C_model_type" value="4"/>
 
 <!-- Only load the specified model -->
<xacro:if value="${model_type == A_model_type}">
<xacro:include filename="/urdf/A_model.xacro"/>
</xacro:if>

<xacro:if value="${model_type == B_model_type}">
<xacro:include filename="/urdf/B_model.xacro"/>
</xacro:if>
  
<xacro:if value="${model_type == C_model_type}">
<xacro:include filename="/urdf/C_model.xacro"/>
</xacro:if>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199949/problem-with-xacro:if-value=%22$%7Bmodel_type-==-a_model_type%7D%22/) by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2014-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can think of a couple of "clean" ways to do this.

I do not know which way is better. There should be other ways to achieve this as well.
With Option-1, `child_X.xacro` can be very small, and is dependent on `parent.xacro`.
In Option-2, each xacro file is not inter-dependent. `wholerobot_model_X.xacro` can be a little larger than Option-1 but still concise enough.

**Option-1**. Split `xacro` files into "parent/abstract" and "child/concrete" files.

parent.xacro:

```
:
<!-- Only load the specified model -->
<xacro:macro name="model_to_be_inserted" params="modelfile_path">
  <xacro:include filename="${modelfile_path}"/>
</xacro:macro>
:
```

child_a.xacro

```
:
<xacro:include filename="parent.xacro" />
:
<xacro:model_to_be_inserted modelfile_path="A_model_type" />
:
```

**Option-2**. Split your robot definition into smaller components as xacro files, then "assemble" them in another xacro for the specific design.

Say, split components of upper-body humanoid into `{head, torso, left_arm, left_hand, right_arm, right_hand}.xacro`, and you want to switch with customize hands.

wholerobot_model_A.xacro

```
:
<xacro:include filename="head.xacro"/>
<xacro:include filename="torso.xacro"/>
<xacro:include filename="left_arm.xacro"/>
<xacro:include filename="A_model_type_l.xacro"/>
<xacro:include filename="right_arm.xacro"/>
<xacro:include filename="A_model_type_r.xacro"/>
:
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0